# quaterinon-like affine transform

Tags: linear-transformations, quaternions

OK, so I know a qautrnion can represent a certain transformation of a basis.  Generally a quaternion of the form

$$a+b\mathbf{i}+c\mathbf{j}+d\mathbf{k}$$

Uniformly expands the basis by $g=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}$, rotates the basis around the vector defined by $(b,c,d)$  with an angle $\theta=2acos(a/g)$.  Basically it transforms a cube to a rotated, resized cube.  I think.

Is there a similar complex-ish formulation for an affine transformation?  i.e. that can transform a cube to a rotated rectangular prism?  Purpose is to do some statistical analysis on such transforms, which seems simpler (still not very simple) as a complex variable than as a deformation tensor.

Comment: *rotates the basis around the vector defined by $(b,c,d)$  with an angle $\theta=2acos(a/g)$.*. You mean via the transformation $x\mapsto qxq^{-1}$?

Comment: I . . guess?  Sorry, I'm an Engineer getting a bit out of my depth here.

Comment: the best luck you'll have is looking into quaternionic alternatives to analytic mappings, but the problem you describe is really a problem for tensors.

Comment: Quaternions are a way to model rotations, which are isometries. If you want to turn a cube into a rectangular prism, you'll have to use matrices.